# Getting data from async Task OnGet with RAZOR PAGES

Tags: c#, .net, razor-pages

I'm novice programmer and I've got some .NET app based on RAZOR PAGES. Whole application works almost half a year but I want to develop it in a more professional way. I'm conneting with MSSQL server and in every element ( OnGet, OnPost, Task(IActionResult), Task(JsonResult) ) always use same structre:

creating IList or Class:

```
public IList<ClassName2> listName = new List<ClassName1>();
public ClassName2 objectname = new ClassName2();
public async Task OnGet(string Komunikat, string Blad, string NumerCyklu)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string sql = "select top 1000 .........";
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);
                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            //if or while 
                            while (reader.Read()) 
                            {
                                //list or class
                                 list.value1= reader.IsDBNull(0) ? null : reader.GetString(0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

So in every page I'm manually decide how  many rows gets from database.
I'd like to make some forms with parameters (DateFrom / DateTo ) and send them with (OnGet/OnPost) to main page.
I'm  not using Core DbContext class.

When I tried use task *"OnGet/OnPost Async Task"* with *"Return Page()"* - the list is always empty. When I tried to use Return with *"Redirect to Page"* - I need to use return objects but then I cant use rest of code from basic 'OnGet'.

Could anyone help me with some basic example ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide some information about your markup? How do you get `Kommunikat`, `Blad` and `NumerCyklu`?

Comment: Komunikat, Blad and NumerCykly are some basic parameters that are sometimes loads when entering the page. Message - information that something has been done correctly, e.g. after Post and return RedirectToPage("/xxx/xxx/Index",
                 new { Komunikat = $"Order added successfully!" }); 
Or after some catch: return RedirectToPage("/xxx/xx/Add",
                    new { Blad = ex.Message }) ;

Comment: Can you add a parameter to your method so it will look like `public async Task OnGet(string Komunikat, string Blad, string NumerCyklu, int limit)`? Can you pass it as `RedirectToPage("/xxx/xxx/Index", new { Komunikat = $"Order added successfully!", limit = 123 });`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put a filter on your page where a user selcts dates and then a post submits a query to the DB? I think that's what you mean. If so you can do this:

Model:

```
public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
public IList<ClassName1> ListName { get; set; }
```

Markup:

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="DateFrom" type="date" />
    <input asp-for="DateTo" type="date" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    string dateFromParam = DateFrom.HasValue ? DateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : (object)DBNull.Value;
    string dateToParam = DateTo.HasValue ? DateTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : (object)DBNull.Value;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT ... WHERE DateColumn >= @DateFrom AND DateColumn <= @DateTo";
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", dateFromParam);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", dateToParam);
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                ListName = new List<ClassName1>();
                while (reader.Read()) 
                {
                    ClassName1 item = new ClassName1();
                    item.Value1 = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? null : reader.GetString(0);
                    // Assign other props
                    ListName.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // After fetching the data, re-render the same page to show the results
    return Page();
}
```

Then with Razor in your View:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.ListName)
{
    <li>@item.Value1</li>
    <!-- Display other properties... -->
}
</ul>
```

Personally, I prefer using LINQ as I am not very good with SQL and LINQ just reads easier for me if you are using EF/DbContext:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    // Assuming you have a DbContext instance named _context
    ListName = await _context.ClassName1s
        .Where(item => (!DateFrom.HasValue || item.DateColumn >= DateFrom.Value)
            && (!DateTo.HasValue || item.DateColumn <= DateTo.Value))
        .ToListAsync();

    return Page();
}
```